# <div> not hiding on click?

Tags: javascript, maven, jsf, xhtml

This `div` should hide on click. I tested the code in notepad++ and it worked. But in a maven project, I added the code to a `JSF` page and it does not hide on click. Why does it not work in a JSF Page? or is something else wrong?

Here is the code:

```
<div id="cookiew">
        <b>This site uses cookies. By continuing to browse the site, you are agreeing to our use of cookies. <b>
        <button type="button" id="cookieb" class="btn btn-default" >OK</button>
        <style>
            #cookiew{
                width: 960px;
                display: block;
                margin-left: auto;
                background-color: red;
                width: 100%;
                text-align: center;
                color: white;
                height: 45px;
                padding-bottom: 5px;
                padding-top: 5px;
            }
            #cookieb{
                margin-left: 3px;
                margin-right: 3px;
            }
        </style>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $("#cookieb").click(function(){
                    $(cookiew).hide();
                });
            });
        </script>
    </div>
```

Also, here are my scripts:

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<h:outputScript library="js" name="myjs.js" />
```

Here is a JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/7dyh5eun/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition too what denise said.
It seems like jquery was not loaded.
Updated jsfiddle see here http://jsfiddle.net/7dyh5eun/4/

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#cookiePrompt').click(function(){
        $('#cookiePrompt').hide();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, that is a strange place to put a script tag. But could the problem be:

```
$(cookiew).hide();
```

should be

```
$("#cookiew").hide();
```

?

Comment: Where should be a good place to put script tags? I changed it to `"#cookiew"` but it still doesnt hide.

Comment: Best place: in its own file. (css really belongs in its own file as well). Other than that, at the top or bottom of the file are more typical places for style and script tags.

Comment: Thank you. Do you have any more suggestions why my code still wont work?